# dynamic chart.js not showing correctly

Tags: php, chart.js

I've this canvas in chartjs whish is not working as i thought it would.
The code below gives me the screenshot at the bottom.
The lines are next to each other and was hoping or 2 lines 1 above the other.
Does somebody know's what I'm doing wrong?

```
<canvas id="graph" data-settings=
                            '{
                              "type": "line",
                              "data":
                              {
                                "datasets":
                                  [{
                            "label": "Total all0",
                            "data": [{"x": "2022-11-15 18:05:32", "y": 0.00476254},{"x": "2022-11-15 18:56:44", "y": 0.00476008},{"x": "2022-11-15 21:02:40", "y": 0.00473502},{"x": "2022-11-15 21:44:15", "y": 0.00473691},{"x": "2022-11-16 09:07:09", "y": 0.00478415},{"x": "2022-11-16 13:22:01", "y": 0.00472505},{"x": "2022-11-17 10:21:24", "y": 0.00474098},{"x": "2022-11-17 11:51:59", "y": 0.00470936},{"x": "2022-11-17 22:58:09", "y": 0.00469389},{"x": "2022-11-18 08:44:04", "y": 0.00470497}],
                            "fill": false,
                            "backgroundColor": "blue",
                            "borderColor": "blue",
                            "hoverBackgroundColor": "#CCCCCC",
                            "hoverBorderColor": "#666666"
                          },{
                            "label": "Total all1",
                            "data": [{"x": "2022-11-15 18:05:34", "y": 0},{"x": "2022-11-15 18:56:46", "y": 0},{"x": "2022-11-15 21:02:41", "y": 0},{"x": "2022-11-15 21:44:16", "y": 0},{"x": "2022-11-16 09:07:10", "y": 0},{"x": "2022-11-16 13:22:02", "y": 0},{"x": "2022-11-17 10:21:25", "y": 0},{"x": "2022-11-17 11:52:01", "y": 0},{"x": "2022-11-17 22:58:10", "y": 0},{"x": "2022-11-18 08:44:05", "y": 0}],
                            "fill": false,
                            "backgroundColor": "blue",
                            "borderColor": "blue",
                            "hoverBackgroundColor": "#CCCCCC",
                            "hoverBorderColor": "#666666"
                          }]},
                            "options":
                            {
                              "responsive": true,
                              "plugins":
                              {
                                "title":
                                {
                                  "display": true,
                                  "text": "title txt",
                                  "fontSize": 150,
                                  "fontColor": "#000"
                                },
                                "legend":
                                {
                                  "position": "top",
                                  "labels": {
                                      "fontColor": "#333",
                                      "fontSize": 16
                                      }
                                },
                                "scales": {
                                    "yAxes": [{
                                    "scaleLabel": {
                                        "display": true,
                                        "labelString": "Value [ ]"
                                    },
                                    "ticks": {
                                        "beginAtZero": true
                                    }
                                    }]
                                }
                              }
                            }

                          }'
                          ></canvas>
```

[image: result_chart]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the type to time for xAxis in the options like this:

```js
options: {
    scales: {
        xAxis: {
            type: "time",
            distribution: "linear"
        }
    }
}
```

Also, there's something wrong with your code. The scales object is inside the plugins object. It should be inside options object.

Here is an example of a line chart with time as x-axis using your data:

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");

var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "line",
    data: {
        datasets:[
            {
                label: "Total all0",
                data: [{ "x": "2022-11-15 18:05:32", "y": 0.00476254 }, { "x": "2022-11-15 18:56:44", "y": 0.00476008 }, { "x": "2022-11-15 21:02:40", "y": 0.00473502 }, { "x": "2022-11-15 21:44:15", "y": 0.00473691 }, { "x": "2022-11-16 09:07:09", "y": 0.00478415 }, { "x": "2022-11-16 13:22:01", "y": 0.00472505 }, { "x": "2022-11-17 10:21:24", "y": 0.00474098 }, { "x": "2022-11-17 11:51:59", "y": 0.00470936 }, { "x": "2022-11-17 22:58:09", "y": 0.00469389 }, { "x": "2022-11-18 08:44:04", "y": 0.00470497 }],
                backgroundColor: "blue",
                borderColor: "blue",
            },
            {
                label: "Total all1",
                data: [{ "x": "2022-11-15 18:05:34", "y": 0 }, { "x": "2022-11-15 18:56:46", "y": 0 }, { "x": "2022-11-15 21:02:41", "y": 0 }, { "x": "2022-11-15 21:44:16", "y": 0 }, { "x": "2022-11-16 09:07:10", "y": 0 }, { "x": "2022-11-16 13:22:02", "y": 0 }, { "x": "2022-11-17 10:21:25", "y": 0 }, { "x": "2022-11-17 11:52:01", "y": 0 }, { "x": "2022-11-17 22:58:10", "y": 0 }, { "x": "2022-11-18 08:44:05", "y": 0 }],
                backgroundColor: "yellow",
                borderColor: "yellow",
            }
        ]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxis: {
                type: "time",
                distribution: "linear",
                time: {
                    unit: "minute",
                    displayFormats: {
                        minute: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<div>
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@^2"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@^3"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-moment@^1"></script>
```

Comment: this totaly works, thanks.